# Jsoup select - why does it include current element?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to understand if I'm missing something, because it seems very bizarre to me why Jsoup includes the current element in the search performed by `select`.

For example (scala code):

```
val el = doc.select("div").first
el.select("div").contains(el) // => true
```

What is the point of this? I see very limited cases where you'd actually want this. Do I need to always use `el.children.select` instead? Is there a nicer method?

Side question: Is there a nicer way to do `el.children.select(s).first`? In Ruby Nokogiri it would be `el.at_css(s)` which is much shorter, is there a similar option in Jsoup?

Comment: Perhaps... you could ask the JSoup people why they designed their API that way? But furthermore, as this behaviour is documented (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) and more likely to get understood than a default "search in children" behaviour, I prefer this API. Further, the API for JSoup `Elements` works as one expectes it: It only searches in the list elements (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#select%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to why the `select` method was implemented the way it did, my only guess would be because it's the most straightforward way to do it if we take into consideration the struct that holds the data resulted by your query.

If we think about `el`, we will see that it is a "tree" representation of the elements that you asked for, having as root the first parent div node. Then you call `select` on that tree. Now it all depends on how you decide to see this tree. Should we treat this "tree" as a whole (include root) or not (discard root)? It's a matter of taste I guess.

If I judge from myself, a lot of people using Jsoup, probably have had some experience on DOM parsing with jQuery. The equivalent would be something like this `$("div").first().find("div")` where `find` is documented as

> Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

This is in agreement with what you stated. It's just a matter of how the two libraries "see" the resulting tree. Jsoup treats the root as one of the nodes, jQuery differentiates the root (as far `find` is concerned).

About the second part of your question.

```
val el = doc.select("div").first
el.children.select(s).first
```

No there isn't. The only way is to change the css selector.

```
val result = doc.select("div:eq(0) " + s).first;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it was confusing to me because of my background from jQuery (and Nokogiri). From a practical standpoint I think the jQuery way makes more sense.

Comment: I agree. It was odd to me at first too, because of my jQuery background. Have fun.